# How to add iPhone6 support in Cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, iphone-6

We started one new project and same time apple released new iPhone6. Whats its resolution and how to add iphone6 image in cocos2d ?

Like below are extension for earlier device

```
 -hd : iphonehd
 -ipad : ipad
 -ipadhd : ipadhd
 -iphone5hd : iphone5
```

So how to add iPhone 6 ?

Comment: Wait until a cocos2d update has been issued. Follow the github repository, watch the develop branch. This change isn't as simple as changing a line of code or two.

Answer (score 1):

Portrait Resolutions:

```
iPhone 6 : 750 X 1334 pixels (4.7inches)
iPhone 6 Plus : 1242 X 2208 pixels (5.5inches)
```

No need to handle these two new resolution. Os itself scaled. In iPhone6, iphone5 graphics used.

**NOTE :**

```
1. #define IS_IPHONE5 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f)
2. #define IS_IPHONE5 (([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width == 568.0f) ? YES : NO )

if(IS_IPHONE5)
```

Now Case 1 fails in iPhone6 and iPhone 6 Plus. So use 2. No other changes needed for iphone6 support.